# How to decrease memory leaks for PAL and CM31 tags?

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak as the picture below. Their tags are CM31 and PAL.

[image: Picture]

By using command prompt I found an upgrade for xHCIPort.sys (it was intel proset wireless software) and using Intel's program I upgraded it and after check there wasn't any upgrade in that program. However as the picture below I still see the xHCIPort.sys which causes the leak. (As in the first picture)

[image: Picture]

Second one is, I can't see anything for CM31 tag in command prompt. So, when I enter `findstr /s CM31 *.*` command to the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers>` directory it just jumping the bottom row and shows nothing.

What can be done for these?

**EDIT**

After checking Pool Usage from WPRUI, I saw the big usages oritinate Gh05 and PfPB tags. It was displaying for CM31 tag nearly 250 MB. I don't care it. I need to decrease the usages for Gh05 and PfPB tags. That's why I wrote the commands for that tags as I mentioned above. However, same thing happened. Nothing happens and seems in command propmt. It is just jumping bottom row..

Comment: do you need more details or is the question answered? if yes, accept it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @magicandre1981 Can you look at the edit section in question again?

Comment: Gh05 = GDI related. so update GPU drivers. PfPB = Prefetcher of Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CM31` tag is used by Windows to load Registry Hive from user profile

[image]

For the `xHCIPort.sys` (Intel USB-IF xHCI USB Host Controller/Intel Wireless Display Driver), there is no way to limit this. Ask this Intel, so that they fix the leak or disable the Intel wireless devices in device manager.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I don't know how you opened that windows, except CM31 tag what their meanings are, and why emphasized some of them but you mean, I can't stop the CM31 tag. Is that correct?

Comment: you need to capture a boot trace with Pool usage to see the data (Install Windows Perf Toolkit, run WPRUI, select Pool usage and Boot for scenario). you can't stop the CM31 usage. and around 240MB are normal usage for CM31.

Comment: I checked my box and I also have 242MB CM31 usage.