# CM31 taking a lot of ram. Followed various guides without a solution

Tags: memory, xperf

On Windows 8.1, the system was using a lot of RAM without me running any programs. I had 4 GB of RAM and upon startup almost 2.5 GB were already used. Following the steps described here [Windows using too much RAM, how to diagnose resource hog](https://superuser.com/questions/674649/windows-using-too-much-ram-how-to-diagnose-resource-hog/674725#674725), I have managed to update or uninstall several obsolete drivers, but still, the CM31 (Registry) processes and MmSt (?) keep taking a lot of RAM.

Here is a screenshot from poolmon:
[image: Here is a screenshot from poolmon]

I suppose I could still work with the first five entries.

I have also used xperf, but it led me nowhere 
[image: Xperf screenshot]

What can I do about CM31 and how could I clear more RAM? Registry defragmentation didn't help.
EDIT: [Procexp overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O49Vf.png)

Comment: Please supply an overview of your running processes. TaskManager or ProcessExplorer. CM31 and MMST are Windows system components working on behalf of other processes. Without any other information on what you are running we can't make any guess at what is going on.

Comment: @Tonny I have added a procexp overview

Comment: [CM31 tag is used by Windows when loading profile hive during boot](https://superuser.com/a/1174512/174557)

Comment: @magicandre1981, thanks. Is there something I can do about its size? I didn't find any answers...

Comment: Can you explain why you think empty RAM is a *good thing*? It generally isn't - the system works faster when recently used & potentially 'next to be used' items are already there.

Comment: how large is your user registry ntuser.dat?

Comment: @Tetsujin, empty RAM is a good thing in cases when you need it to be of use for other applications. Used RAM is bad in cases applications like faulty drivers of malware occupy it instead of applications that actually need it. At least, that is my take.

Comment: @magicandre1981, it's 7 MB.

Comment: how large are the system related registry hives (those ones are stored in C:\Windows\System32\config)?

Comment: @magicandre1981 the largest are: SOFTWARE : 100 MB, COMPONENTS 76 MB, SYSTEM 11 MB.

Comment: ok, [capture a boottrace](https://superuser.com/a/976646/174557) in WPRUI.exe, select "Pool Usage" and Registry IO to capture pool and registry activity. zip the generated ETL as 7z and share the 7z via OneDrive.

Comment: @magicandre1981, thanks! I haven't tried this one yet. I do not use OneDrive, but here is a google drive link. The password is Atlas456. https://drive.google.com/open?id=10bfEhv3AMlCQDh9Kac9WK8Nph707hWDN

Comment: I can't see any CM31 usage in the trace (I get warnings that events are lost, so maybe the CM31 data are lost ). I see that the loading of driver vflt (Shrewsoft Lightweight Filter ??) causes a 100s delay during boot. remove this and capture a new trace, maybe this new trace includes all data

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here it is. Strangely enough, it is ten times the size. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JZVuKdkt_NARCBCrm6T_mktDzjgQh_v_

Comment: this time I see that data but only 134MB usage. I also can't see the registry hive operation (only query/open of keys). run this command: **xbootmgr -trace boot -traceFlags BASE+CSWITCH+POOL+REGISTRY+REG_HIVE -stackwalk PoolAlloc+RegHiveInit+RegHiveLink** to capture the hive information

Comment: I looked at the disk IO activity and saw that 3rd party drivers from Easus backup are involved during load of the hive. maybe this causes the higher usage. so use the 50/50 way (disable half of 3rd party tools, look if issue occurs, if yes, disable again of of remaining drivers , if it is fixed, enable 50 of the prev disabled drivers) until you see which driver/software causes it

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks again. While I have tried tinkering with the loaded drivers, I have twice ended with a system restore (I was disabling only third party drivers, ofc) so I would prefer not doing that. However, I have the trace on this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YwvOaXwPxNvRqsCl-zBrkPLOKPx9gFrC

Comment: ok, \SystemRoot\System32\Config\SOFTWARE is 100MB but the interesting thing is \??\C:\Windows\AppCompat\Programs\Amcache.hve gets also loaded via CM31 tag allocation. so do you run later a lot of apps in compatibility mode?

Comment: @magicandre1981 No, none. Or at least none I would know of...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WHokSvsnxjPbKm4tA_nni0KIKIu2p4j0 - rammap when most of applications is off. Might be relevant

Comment: according to the picture the usage is expected. there is no real issue of your system. that is the usage. in Win10 1803, the usage will be reduced by putting it into a [registry process](https://winaero.com/blog/registry-process-windows-10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory usage of the CM31 tag is normal for Windows. To see how Windows uses the pool you need to install the Windows Performance Toolkit, which is part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (which also works on Windows 8.1).

[image]
<sup>(all other entries can be unselected)</sup>

Now open a cmd.exe as admin and run this command:

> xbootmgr -trace boot -traceFlags BASE+CSWITCH+POOL+REGISTRY+REG_HIVE
>   -stackwalk PoolAlloc+RegHiveInit+RegHiveLink

This reboots Windows and captures the Pool usage during boot.

After Reboot make a double click on the generated ETL file to open the ETL in Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA.exe) and move Registry Hive graph to Analysis pane:

[image]

Here you see which hives get loaded via CM31 tag:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So Windows loads software, drivers, user registry hive and also a hive for application compatibility settings (`C:\Windows\AppCompat\Programs\Amcache.hve`).

To improve the performance of your PC, add more RAM, 4GB is really low end today, there are already Android phones which 6GB RAM. To improve boot speed replace the slow ST3250410AS drive with a SSD.

Comment: Well, I guess that is as far as we have got. I understand that 1 GB is normal. Thank you for your help.